# Php array display table

Tags: php, arrays

I have some array

```
    Array
(
    [Position] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

        )

    [Resources, Systems & Equipment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

        )

    [Security & Safety] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

        )

    [Rewards & Recognition] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Capability] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Achievement] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Growth & Development] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Balance] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Colleagues] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Manager] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Senior Leadership] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

    [Organisation] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [question_summary] => 

                )

        )

)
```

Then i have a 'table' with 3 column

How to make my array to be
     | Position   | Capability   | Colleagues    |
     | Resources  | Achievement  | Manager       |
     | Security   | Growth       | Senior        |
     | Rewards    | Balance      | Organisation  |

Thanx

Comment: yup.....im weak in array :D

Comment: can you post the codes that you make so that we can pin point what you missed..

Comment: i used 
if ($count % 3 == 1)
{
//code to make next column
}

Comment: edit your post above and put in the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should run through with some `%`(modulo)-magic:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$numColumns = 3;
$newArray = array_fill(0, $numColumns, array());
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    $newArray[$i%$numColumns][floor($i/$numColumns)] = $array[$i];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

See [this PHP-Fiddle](http://codepad.org/MLVZHrK4)